# Is this a bug or am I using the wrong Log() overload?

Tags: nlog

When logging like this:

   `try {}
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Log.Error(ex);
   }`

The `${message}` holds the entire `Exception.ToString()` and `${exception:format=message}` outputs `Exception.Message`.

I expected `${message}` to be blank or possibly have automatically gotten the value of `Exception.Message`. (Not because they share a name. Because exception objects get special treatment in NLog.)

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or I just have the wrong expectations of that Log.Error() overload.  Should I instead do:

`Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);`

or file a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [known bug](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1034). Because of backwards-compatibly we will fix this not before NLog 5.